# Subtracting 5 Business days from a given date field in pyspark or hive

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I have a need to subtract 5 business days from a data field in a spark data frame.
Below is my sample data.

```
+-----------+---------------+
|cust_id    |agreement_date |
+-----------+---------------+
|901866745  |2021-01-28     |
|901866746  |2021-01-29     |
|901866747  |2021-02-02     |
|901866748  |2021-02-05     |
+-----------+---------------+
```

I need to derive another field to this data frame called `prcs_strt_dt` which is `agreement_date` - 5 Business days. Expected output is below.

```
+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|cust_id    |agreement_date |prcs_strt_dt   |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|901866745  |2021-01-28     |2021-01-21     |
|901866746  |2021-01-29     |2021-01-22     |
|901866747  |2021-02-02     |2021-01-26     |
|901866748  |2021-02-05     |2021-01-29     |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

I can use pyspark or hive but the limitation is that I cannot use external libraries.
Can someone help me??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `agreement_date` is a weekday, then subtract `7` days from it.
If it's a Saturday or Sunday, then subtract `5` or `6` days respectively.

To get the weekday from the date, you can use `date_format`. For date subtractions, use `date_sub`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format, expr
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('prcs_strt_dt', F.when(date_format('agreement_date', 'u') == 6, \
    expr("date_sub(agreement_date , 5)"))\
    .when(date_format('agreement_date', 'u') == 7, expr("date_sub(agreement_date , 6)"))\
    .otherwise(expr("date_sub(agreement_date , 7)"))).show()

+---------+--------------+------------+
|  cust_id|agreement_date|prcs_strt_dt|
+---------+--------------+------------+
|901866745|    2021-01-28|  2021-01-21|
|901866746|    2021-01-29|  2021-01-22|
|901866747|    2021-02-02|  2021-01-26|
|901866748|    2021-02-05|  2021-01-29|
|901866748|    2021-02-06|  2021-02-01|
|901866748|    2021-02-07|  2021-02-01|
+---------+--------------+------------+
```